# Drag elements from collapsed sidebar to body

Tags: jquery, draggable

I'm trying to drag elements from a sidebar panel to the page body but it doesn't drop at body.

I've already tried a lot of options when I initilize the draggable element but without success.

This is how my draggable is initilized:

```
$('.draggable-dash').draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: 'clone',
            appendTo: '.dropdashboard',
            containment: 'body',
            //zIndex: 2500,
            scroll: false,
            cursorAt: { top: -5, left: -5 },
            start: function(){
                $(this).hide();
            },
            stop: function(){
                $(this).show()
            }            
        });
```

And this is the panel css

```
.theme-panel {
    position: fixed;
    right: -175px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 1020;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 175px;
    transition: right .2s linear;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.theme-panel.theme-panel-lg .theme-panel-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Here's a [image](https://i.postimg.cc/XJ82cM46/drop.gif) of what is happening. As you can see, the position of element when it's on draggle mode is also wrong.

I've no idea of what to do to fix it :(

Comment: What happends when you change cursorAt?

Comment: Nothing.. No matter what value I put on it, the result is the same.